# reactjs Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs

Getting this error on every browser when trying to render a simple paragraph in React:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target
>   container is not a DOM element.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/base.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>this should not be seen</p>
    </div>
    <script src="../../build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script>
      "use strict";
      var BoxTile = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
          return React.createElement("p", null, "Imageine this is a tile...");
        }
      });
      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BoxTile), document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remove 'ver 14' from the title, because this error has nothing to do with the version of React. Older versions also will give you this error (or something alike).

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` can not find the relevant node because `container` is a class attribute and not id.

Change

```
<div class="container">
  <p>this should not be seen</p>
</div>
```

To

```
<div id="container">
  <p>this should not be seen</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, replaced it with document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0] and works fine